# recursive call through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion

i am using the following code to recursively call through ajax.

```
function ajax_pay(i)
{
    var opt=document.getElementById("fpayee").options;
        payid=opt[i].value;
        alert(i);
       if(payid==""){return;}

    alert(payid);
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } 
        else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&  xmlhttp.status == 200) {


       document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML=i;
        i++;   
        ajax_pay(i); 


            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","closeup.php?pid="+payid,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

here fpayee is a combobox and i am initialising the recursion through ajax_pay(0);

But the problem is it runs only for once.
please help;

Comment: Are there any errors showing up?. Try to debug and check the value of i that you are sending or check in the network tab is the response even coming for the next call to execute

Comment: Watch your variable declarations. `xmlhttp` and `payid` are both declared in the global scope. Calling this function recursively will overwrite those values and confuse the code.

Comment: @Hobo.how it is confusing. i think this is simple recursion and xmlhttp will be used at once in function call

Comment: Check what happens after the first request: if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&  xmlhttp.status == 200) { alert("hi")  }

Comment: you need to call it on some click event <button type="button" onclick="ajax_pay(0)">Change Content</button> and make sure that  xmlhttp.open("GET","closeup.php?pid="+payid,true); is correct.check your file name.your code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

i Got it. I was calling it wrongly.this the write way to do

```
 <button type="button" onclick="ajax_pay(0)">
```